# Unity iOS build does not create any files

Tags: ios, xcode, unity-game-engine

I have created an XCode project through Unity in order to build for iOS, and the build succeeds with a few warnings, but there is nothing in the build folder.  It takes a few minutes to build, so it seems like it's doing something, but nothing is there.

When I deleted the empty placeholder build folders that come with the Unity-generated XCode project just to see if it creates anything, the build folder does not even get created.  I have tried changing the bundle identifiers in Unity and on my provisioning profiles to match each other, but it hasn't helped.

I am building for Generic iOS Device as opposed to an actual Device connected to my Mac.  Is that part of the issue?

[image: Build Results]

Comment: what are you expecting to see in the build folder?

Comment: The binary.  Is it impossible to create one for a Generic iOS device?

Comment: you build the binary through Product > Archive, after building the Organizer Windows appears where you can export a binary either for ad hoc or app store deployment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Jean Luc answered this question, but he wrote a comment, so I am posting it here for clarity:
you build the binary through Product > Archive, after building the Organizer Windows appears where you can export a binary either for ad hoc or app store deployment